# Conditional Formatting Max and Min values along rows

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-formatting

I have a table similar to below:

| Sector | 4/1/2022 | 5/1/2022 | 6/1/2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 05 | 12 |
| B | 18 | 20 | 09 |
| C | 02 | 09 | 12 |

1. I want the **max value** in every row to appear in **green font**
   and    **min value** in every row to appear in **red font**.
2. While calculating the min, I want to **exclude 0 from the
   calculation.**

I tried using the below code however it highlights the cell instead of changing font colour.

```
df.style.highlight_min(color = 'red', axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(df.iloc[:,1:].style.highlight_max(axis=1, props='color:green;')
         .highlight_min(axis=1, props='color:red;'))
# or
(df.set_index('Sector').style.highlight_max(axis=1, props='color:green;')
         .highlight_min(axis=1, props='color:red;'))
```

**UPDATE**
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70389257/15521392) post with few changes the function works for your task without a need of the `props` argument

```
def highlight_min_max(x):
    color_min = 'color: green'
    color_max = 'color: red'
    # condition
    mask_min = x.eq(x[x>.01].min()) #excluding 0 when searching for min
    mask_max = x.eq(x.max())
    # empty Series of styles
    s = pd.Series('', index=x.index)

    # set columns by conditions
    return s.mask(mask_min, color_min).mask(mask_max, color_max)

df.set_index('Sector').style.apply(highlight_min_max, axis=1)
```

[image: d]

Comment: Thanks, Getting the error: Styler.highlight_max() got an unexpected keyword argument 'props'

Comment: hm, I used your example input and the code worked without a problem. as you can see here in de [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.highlight_max.html) is a valid input argument. I just saw, that `props` is new in version 1.3.0., I guess you have an old version.

Comment: Gotcha, any workaround?

Comment: This worked amazingly with the input I had provided. However I am encountering another issue, I have added two more columns to my df, one of them being: 

df['1Y Tight'] = df[df>0].min(axis=1) which gives me error:
 TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Styler' and 'int'

This error did not exist before I used the conditional formatting function.

Comment: @Saanchi `dataframe.style` returns "Return a Styler object containing methods for building a styled HTML representation for the DataFrame." [see documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.html). It doesn't return a dataframe, that's why you get the error. I guess if using styler it should be the last step of your data analysis. If you are happy with the answer as it is to your question, please consider voting/accepting it.